# wordpress like static home page and other dynamic pages in angular 4

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I am new in angular development and i have a query in development of my current project. I want to make my home page static and i want other pages to load with header and footer. I have seen this in wordpress and i want to implement the same with angular 4.
I have tried this in angular

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent }
];
```

and in template i have set something like this

```
<app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: this will work fine as long as one of your component is static and a route is mapped to that static component

Answer (score 1):

If you load component like below

```
<app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

then every component will load with header and footer including your home page as well.
To over come this issue you have two solution.

1) Put condition "***ngIf**" in both header and footer tag and check if router-link/component is not home.

2) separate home module and lazy load other component. by using this way you can seprate HTML for home component and other component as well.

Also, for routing use below snippet.

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent }
];
```

This will redirect you to home page in-case if any route doesn't match or if its blank.